# Accordion menu: how to open all at start

Tags: javascript, html, css, accordion

I have started making an accordion menu, html:

```
<button class="accordion">New Attendees</button>
<div class="panel">
    <p>How do I get started?</p>
    <p>I'm stuck! Where can I get help?</p>
 </div>
 <button class="accordion">Instrument Simulations</button>
 <div class="panel">
    <p>What are some tools I can use?</p>
    <p>How can I obtain an estimate?</p>
</div>
```

With css:

```
.accordion:after {
    content: "\002B";
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.active {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

And I've used javascript to give it functionality:

```
<script>
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Right now, all the accordions are collapsed on page load, but I want all them to be open by default. What's a good way to open all them by default? I thought that I might be able to switch the css to .panel(display:block;} but that seems to mess up everything else too much to go about it that way. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript works on the element itself so the style property should be applied on the html and you were inserting it on the css file. That's why it was messing all up.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
        to highlight the button that controls the panel */
        this.classList.toggle("active");

        /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
        var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (panel.style.display === "block") {
            panel.style.display = "none";
        } else {
            panel.style.display = "block";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.accordion:after {
    content: "\002B";
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion:hover {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.active {
    background-color: #333;
    color: white;
}

.active:after {
    content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
    padding: 18px;
    background-color: white;
    display: none;
    transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion active">New Attendees</button>
<div class="panel" style="display:block;">
    <p>How do I get started?</p>
    <p>I'm stuck! Where can I get help?</p>
 </div>
 <button class="accordion active">Instrument Simulations</button>
 <div class="panel" style="display:block;">
    <p>What are some tools I can use?</p>
    <p>How can I obtain an estimate?</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the toggling into a function and call it for every accordion at the end of the script part. You can avoid toggling breaking your layout by putting one button and one panel together into a div container. Then apply `float: left` to all containers. It should look like that:

```js
function toggle(acc) {
  /* Toggle between adding and removing the "active" class,
      to highlight the button that controls the panel */
  acc.classList.toggle("active");

  /* Toggle between hiding and showing the active panel */
  var panel = acc.nextElementSibling;
  if (panel.style.display === "block") {
    panel.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    panel.style.display = "block";
  }
}

// This is called when document is loaded, it toggles all accordions
function toggleAll() {
  var accs = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < accs.length; i++) {
    toggle(accs[i]);
  }
}

var accs = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < accs.length; i++) {
  accs[i].onclick = function() {
    toggle(this); // Use toggle function
  }
}
toggleAll();
```

```css
.accordion:after {
  content: "\002B";
  color: #777;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.active:after {
  content: "\2212";
}

.panel {
  padding: 18px;
  background-color: white;
  display: none;
  transition: 0.2s ease-out;
}

.container {
  /* Floating the container will also float its content*/
  float: left;
}

</style>
```

```html
<!-- A wrapper around your accordions -->
<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">New Attendees</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>How do I get started?</p>
    <p>I'm stuck! Where can I get help?</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <button class="accordion">Instrument Simulations</button>
  <div class="panel">
    <p>What are some tools I can use?</p>
    <p>How can I obtain an estimate?</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope I could help you.